# How to show that the full faithfulness of a functor preserved under an action of finite flat algebra?

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, category-theory, tensor-products

Let $R, S,T$ be three commutative rings  with $R \subset S \subset T$ and the map $ S \to T$ is faithfully flat.

Assumme a functor $F: \mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{D}$ between two categories, where $\mathscr{C}$ is the category of $S$-modules and $\mathscr{D}$ is the category of $T$-modules.

Now consider a finite flat $R$-alebra $A$.

**Question:**

How to show the functor $ \mathscr{C} \otimes A \to \mathscr{D} \otimes A$ is fully faithful provided the functor $F: \mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{D}$ is fully faithful.

**Note:** Here by notation $\mathscr{C} \otimes A$,  I want to mean we are taking action of the finite flat $R$-algebra $A$ or just **scalar extension**  by $A$.

$$------------------------------------$$
**My efforts:**

Given that $F: \mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{D}$ is fully faithful. So for any $S$-modules $M,N \in \mathscr{C}$, the functor $F$ induces the map $$F_{M,N}: \text{Hom}_{\mathscr{C}}(M,N) \to \text{Hom}_{\mathscr{D}}(F(M),F(N)),$$  which is bijective. So for any $S$-module homomorphism $f: M\to N$ in category $\mathscr{C}$, we get a unique $T$-module homomorphism $F_{M,N}(f): F(M) \to F(N)$ in category $\mathscr{D}$ by the injectiveness property. Also by the surjective property, for every $T$-module homomorphism $F_{M,N}(g): F(M) \to F(N)$ in category $\mathscr{D}$ there exists a $S$-module homomorphism $f: M \to N$ in category $\mathscr{C}$ which corresponds to each other.

Now we consider the action of the finite flat $R$-algebra $A$ on every modules of $\mathscr{C}$ and $\mathscr{D}$ such as $ M \otimes_R A$ or $N \otimes_R A$ or $F(M) \otimes_R A$ or $F(N) \otimes_R A$ etc. We can then think of the   functor $F: M\to N$ and the $S$-module homomorphism $f:M \to N$ as follows:
$$ {\color{red}{F \otimes 1}}: \mathscr{C} \otimes A \to \mathscr{D} \otimes A, \ \text{and} \ f \otimes 1: M \otimes_R A \to N \otimes_R A,$$  (where $A$ can be thought of as a category of single object (a $R$-module) along identity map $1$).

Thus it seems, by the property of product categories, $${\color{red}{(F \otimes 1)}}_{M,N} (f \otimes 1)=F_{M,N}(f) \otimes F_{M,N}(1),$$ where $1$ denotes the identity map. So it seems to me that the flatness property of $A$ and the map $S \to T$ being faithfully flat, the functor $F \otimes A$ induces the **bijective** map
\begin{align}
{\color{red}{(F \otimes 1)}}_{M,N}: &\text{Hom}_{\mathscr{C} \otimes A}(M \otimes_R A,N \otimes_R A) \\ & \to  \text{Hom}_{\mathscr{D} \otimes A}({\color{red}{(F \otimes 1)}}(M \otimes_R A), {\color{red}{(F \otimes 1)}}(N \otimes_RA)), \end{align} which answers question $(1)$, I think. Perhaps we can consider the following diagram for better understanding:
\begin{align}
\matrix{
\mathscr{C} & \overset{F}{ \longrightarrow} & \mathscr{D} 
\cr  \downarrow  && \downarrow 
\cr \mathscr{C} \otimes A & \overset{{\color{red}{F \otimes 1}}}{\longrightarrow} & \mathscr{D} \otimes A}
\end{align}

Any comment please